# How to translate an imperative task in prolog

Tags: prolog, declarative

I have a functor that calculate the Manhattan distance in a N-puzzle domain of a single tile:

```
distanzaTile(Stato, Pos, Dis) :-
  dim(D),
  nth0(Pos, Stato, Elem),
  Elem == v,
  Y is floor(abs((9 - (Pos + 1))/D)),
  X is mod(abs(9 - (Pos + 1)), D),
  Dis is X+ Y.
  !.
distanzaTile(Stato, Pos, Dis) :-
  dim(D),
  nth0(Pos, Stato, Elem),
  Y is floor(abs((Elem - (Pos + 1))/D)),
  X is mod(abs(Elem - (Pos + 1)), D),
  Dis is X+ Y.
```

where `Stato` is an array, `Pos` is the current position in the array taken into account, `Dis` is the actual result. 
Now, I have to cycle through all the elements of `Stato` and sum all the `Dis`s.
Thinking imperative I'd go for a `for` cycle. How to achieve something similar recursively?

Comment: So, what is your structure of `stato`? Is a list of integers? So `stato` is somethig like `L = [1,2,..]` ?

Comment: @damianodamiano Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `Stato` as input and as counter as follow:

```
ricorri(_, [], _, A, A).
ricorri(Stato, [_|T], Pos, In, Out) :-
  distanzaTile(Stato, Pos, Dis),
  Pos2 is Pos + 1,
  In2 is In + Dis,
  ricorri(Stato, T, Pos2, In2, Out).
```

Hope it may help someone.

Comment: But, why did you insert `[_|T]` even if you don't use `T`? To examine each element of Stato (if this is a list) you can do something like `[H|T]` where in `H` you have the nth-element of `Stato`...

Comment: Well I'm using that list to control the recursion progression. Since there is no `while` or `for` cycle i came out with this idea.